# ASP.NET Website saves the variable even after closing

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

My asp.net website saves the variable of the items in the list (shopping cart) even after the website stops running. This is dangerous because other users logging in will see the same item list (shopping cart).
I add items to the list and then I close the browser, then I re-run the website and add the items to the shopping cart but it still shows the items I added before re-opening the browser.
This didn't happen when I used a web application before and used a very similar code. Is there a way to resolve this issue?

On the client side, I have got a gridview full of shopping items with the button to add to shopping cart:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "AddToCart")
        {
            int rowIndex = ((GridViewRow)((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer).RowIndex;
            GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[rowIndex];
            Label ID = (Label)row.FindControl("lblItemId");
            int itemID = Convert.ToInt32(ID.Text);
            lstCart.Items.Clear();
            OrderClass.AddToCart(itemID);
            lstCart.DataSource = OrderClass.ViewAllOrderItem();
            lstCart.DataBind();

            Button clicked = (Button)row.FindControl("btnAddToCart");
            clicked.Enabled = false;

            Button remove = (Button)row.FindControl("btnRemoveFromCart");
            remove.Visible = true;
        }
```

The method that this is invoking is from the static class called order class which looks like this:

```
private static List<Tuple<string, string>> allItems = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
    private static List<string> itemList;

     public static void AddToCart(int itemID)
        {
            ItemCart.Add(itemID);
        }
```

The method that serves as a datasource the listbox to display all the items in the shopping cart is as follows:

```
public static List<string> ViewAllOrderItem()
    {
        allItems = ItemCart.GetAllOrderItems();
        itemList = new List<string>();
        foreach (Tuple<string, string> eachItem in allItems)
        {
            itemList.Add("Item Name= " + eachItem.Item1 + " , Price= " + eachItem.Item2);
        }
        return itemList;
    }
```

The method in a static class called Itemcart that this Order class calls is

```
private static List<int> orderItems = new List<int>();

     public static void Add(int itemID)
        {
            orderItems.Add(itemID);
        }
```

and

```
public static List<Tuple<string,string>> GetAllOrderItems()
    {
        return ShoppingItems.GetItems(orderItems);       
    }
```

The method in the static class shopping items that the ItemCart invokes is:

```
public static List<Tuple<string, string>> GetItems(List<int> itemID)
    {
        List<Tuple<string, string>> currentItemsList = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();

        using (DataConnection con = new DataConnection())
        {
            foreach (int i in itemID)
            {
                string itemName = con.GolfItems.Where(gi => gi.ItemID == i).Select(gi => gi.ItemName).FirstOrDefault();
                string itemPrice = con.GolfItems.Where(gi => gi.ItemID == i).Select(gi => gi.ItemPrice).FirstOrDefault();
                currentItemsList.Add(Tuple.Create(itemName, itemPrice));
            }
        }
        return currentItemsList;
    }
```

Comment: a [mcve] would be helpful. as this stands theres too much that could be causing this.

Comment: If you can provide some code it would really help to see where the problem lies

Comment: @DanielA.White I have added the code and hope it fits the Minimal, complete and verifiable example standard. Please have a look.

Comment: @MichaelDotKnox I have added the code. Please take a look

Comment: When you say that the above code is on the client side, is it really on the server side?  Client side code would typically be something that runs on something other than the server itself, such as in a browser or in a client application on a user's machine.  ASP.Net code is typically server side code, not client code.  Just want to be sure.

Comment: @MichaelDotKnox Yeah its on the server side of the aspx page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is a result of the static classes that you have.  This can be very dangerous in a web environment if it is not done correctly.  When you have a static class it is very easy to have a race condition, where one session sets the value on a static property or variable that is then used by another session.

My recommendation is that you refactor to change the static classes and static methods to non-static classes and methods, and your problem will most likely go away.

Hope that helps.